# Edit auto fill when can't find source utilized

Tags: iphone

Able to edit name because information and contact was incorrect however the address that is sometimes offered through auto fill on my 6+ I cannot edit because I don't know where their getting that information from it was not attached any credit cards or I haven't lived there since using the smart phone only previously synchronizing  Contacts of older phone with Google accident line as my only guess

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand.  Can you please edit it to use proper grammar and punctuation?  Also, be a bit more specific with what your exact problem is and what you already did to resolve it.  - From Review

Comment: A screenshot might also help to give people here some clues on what you are looking at.